# Micheals Hartl Tutorial chapter 11 undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm going through Hartls Tutorial but with some small modification. I stucked on connecting microposts with authors.

I have the following error:

```
 undefined method `content' for #<Post:0x4cea7b8>
Extracted source (around line #4):

<li id="post-<%= post.id %>">
<%= link_to gravatar_for(post.user, size: 50), post.user %>
<span class="user"><%= link_to post.user.name, post.user %></span>
<span class="content"><%= post.content %></span>
<span class="timestamp">
Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago.
</span>
```

my _post.html.erb

```
<li id="post-<%= post.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(post.user, size: 50), post.user %>
  <span class="user"><%= link_to post.user.name, post.user %></span>
  <span class="content"><%= post.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
</li>
```

my users/show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<h1>
  <%= gravatar_for @user %>
  <%= @user.name %>
</h1>
<div class="col-md-8">
  <% if @user.posts.any? %>
      <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.posts.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="posts">
        <%= render @posts %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @posts %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

my schema.rb file

```
  create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.text      "body"
    t.integer   "user_id"
    t.integer   "post_id"
    t.timestamp "created_at"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "message"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "posts", ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id_and_created_at"
  add_index "posts", ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"
```

schema.rb the rest

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_digest"
    t.boolean  "admin"
    t.string   "activation_digest"
    t.boolean  "activated",         default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["name"], name: "index_users_on_name", unique: true

end
```

Comment: Post your schema.rb file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your _post.html.erb file, change: `<span class="content"><%= post.content %></span>` to `<span class="content"><%= post.message %></span>` and it should work.

The reason you're getting the "undefined method" error is because when you created your Post model, you used "message" as the attribute name but in your _post.html.erb file, you're trying to access a non-existent "content" attribute.